# Text Area new lines from mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm sending text from a text area which is being sent into a mysql database and then being shown elsewhere on another page.

If i input for example:

```
text
text
text
```

into the text area, i simply receive

```
text text text
```

I understand i need to create a new line some how between the text, but really unsure on the way to go about it as it is being stored in MySQL as

```
text||text||text
```

```html
  <div class="panel-heading">Addservices</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="block">
                          <form method="POST" action="page.php">
                    <p>Add service title:</p>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="servicetitle" value=""><br />
                    </div><div class="block">
                    <p>Add service content:</p>

                    <textarea id="b" type="text" class="form-control" name="servicecontent"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit">
                    </form>
                    </div>
```

Code where it is being pulled from

```html
  <?php
                        $getService = $conn->query("SELECT id, value FROM customerlanding WHERE element = 'service'");
                        while ($row = $getService->fetch_assoc()) {
                          $id = $row['id'];
                          $split = explode("||", $row['value']);
                          echo'
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="text-column text-column-centralized tex-column-icon-lg this-animate" data-animate="fadeInLeft">
                                  <div class="text-column-icon">
                                      <span style="background-color:'; echo $result['primarycolour']; echo '"class="fa"></span>
                                  </div>
                                  <h4>';
                                  echo $split[0];
                                  echo '</h4>
                                  <div class="text-column-info">
                                  ';
                                  echo $split[1];
                                  echo '
                                  </div>
                                  </div>
                          </div>';
                      }

                         ?>
```

.

```html
if(isset($_POST['servicetitle'])){
 $service = $_POST['servicetitle']."||".$_POST['servicecontent'];
 $insertservice = $conn->query("INSERT INTO `customer`(`customerid`, `element`, `value`) VALUES ('10','service','$service')");
```

Comment: Show us your way of inserting data into database.

Comment: You most likely have the text with newline in the database already, it's just that HTML doesn't interpret newlines when you're displaying the text. Try using `nl2br()` on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```html
  echo  nl2br($split[1]);
```